# How to serialize JSON Array into Java HasMap, using specific field as a key with GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

For example, given JSON:

```
[
{"id":"3", "location":"NewYork", "date":"yesterday"},
{"id":"4", "location":"Moscow", "date":"today"}
]
```

resulting HashMap:

```
<"3", POJOLocation("NewYork", "yesterday")>
<"4", POJOLocation("Moscow", "today")>
```

where POJOLocation is a Java object:

```
class POJOLocation {
private String location;
private String date;
// etc
}
```

I've tried using custom deserializer, but it was really bloated with generic's tokens and hackish typeOfs. Perhaps there is a simple efficient solution?

Comment: Your json is actually invalid - first and last curly brackets are not needed, unless you give a name to your array

Comment: @dipanda Yep, you are right. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a `POJOLocationId` class:

```
class POJOLocationId {
private int id;
private String location;
private String date;
// etc
}
```

Then deserialize & loop over the resulting `List` populating your `HashMap` as you go?

Comment: That would require A LOT of memory.

Comment: @user3809151 hardly - it's one extra object per entry in your list/map. If that's an issue for the amount of data you're handling you might prefer to use Gson's streaming API.

Answer (score 0):

Gson is designed to make serializing Java objects to their JSON *equivalent* painless. If you're trying to represent a Java data structure as a different type of JSON structure you're not going to have a lot of fun writing serializers and deserializers. At that point you might consider a lower-level JSON parser and simply implement the parsing you want yourself. Rather than representing your data one way in JSON and another way in Java (and thus running into the hassle of transforming between them) you might consider refactoring either your data structure or your data so they're more similar.

That said the easiest thing to do with Gson (which is really not that bad, memory and time-wise) is to use a wrapper type and then transform the input/output before using it. Something like so (borrowing from Tom Mac's type name):

```
private static final Type LIST_TYPE =
    new TypeToken<List<POJOLocationId>>() {}.getType();

public String serialize(Map<Integer, POJOLocation> locations) {
  List<POJOLocationId> locationsList = original.entrySet().stream()
     .map(e -> new POJOLocationId(e.getKey(), e.getValue()).collect(toList());
  return gson.toJson(locationsList);
}

public Map<Integer, POJOLocation> deserialize(String json) {
  List<POJOLocationId> locationsList = gson.fromJson(json, LIST_TYPE);
  return locationsList.stream()
      .collect(toMap(l -> l.getId(), new POJOLocation(l)));
}
```

You certainly can get this same behavior with a custom deserializer, but this works, it's clean, and it's easy to read. The garbage collector should have no trouble cleaning up these temporary wrappers as soon as these methods return.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Gson, but unfortunately real-world JSON cases will give you a lot of pain if serialized directly to POJOs -- I already use custom generic deserializer just to extract useful data from a bloat of meta-data that I get from API.

Comment: @foverzar and using a wrapper class to transform them from the JSON format to the way you want to represent it is a standard practice. Gson's primary use case is for creating a one-to-one mapping between the JSON structure and your class structure. If that isn't the way you want to represent your data in memory, that's fine - use a wrapper.